# Inspect sent messages via websocket from the client

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

newbie here!

Learning the JavaScript and Nodejs environments I'm working on a websocket project (using the ws node module on the server side)

From the client I use:

```
connection = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.x.x:1607');
```

on the server I use:

```
wsServer.on('request', function(r){   ...});
```

If I console.log(r),  I see an enormous message coming in from the client side and I would like to inspect that sent message from the client (not from the nodejs server) Is that possible?
Many thanks!

Is there anyway I could inspect that message from the client side?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Node.js. You could use the [Chrome dev tools](/questions/5751495/debugging-websocket-in-google-chrome) or Whireshark.

Comment: right, I could do that, but is there a way that I can 'see' that message from the client at the client? Some kind of JavaScript method that I can use?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. The web browser is the client. You could call `console.log(data)` before calling `connection.send(data)` or save it to web storage or into an array or …

Comment: @thewall as already suggested, use Chrome's dev tools, look for "WS" under _Network_. It'll show the frames the client sends, and also what it receives from the server.

Comment: Thanks guys, Let me try to explain a bit better... When the browser loads my html, a new WebSocket connection is started and initial data is sent from the browser to the WebSocket server. I understand that I can sniff it wit Dev Tools/WireShark, but if I want to use the initial message sent at runtime in the client, is there a way to evaluate that initial message?  Many thanks!